# Symfony - render or redirect?

Tags: symfony, routes

I made an API call with /seat-number/add route that renders a form and updates the database. But when I change

```
return $this->render('@AdminTemplates/pages/seat-number-add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

to

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('seat_number_list');
```

my add button on index page won't throw from index page to add page..

Here is my whole api call

```
    public function seatEditAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $edit = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Seats::class)->find($id);

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($edit)
        ->add('seatNumber', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Seat Number', 'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Update', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right action-save']))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('@AdminTemplates/pages/seat-number-edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect when the form has been successfully completed, you need to put your second `return` statement inside the `if` block.

The action you wrote is invoked twice in the normal user flow: the first time it displays the form and the second time it is called on the form submission to validate it and perform whatever logic is needed. The if statement checks which of these two cases is the current one and provides different execution paths.
This is why you need to keep the existing return statement: its job is to display the form on the first visit (and do it again if the validation fails).

I also note that inside the same `if` block you obtained the entity manager but apparently did not perform any business logic. That is where you'd be expected to call some service that implements whatever business operation needs to be done.

Comment: ` if ($this->render('@AdminTemplates/pages/seat-number-edit.html.twig', array( 'form' => $form->createView(),))){};return $this->redirectToRoute('seat_number_list');`  still does the same.. no redirection

Answer (score 0):

I just added two return statements and it works..

```
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('seat_number_list');

    }

    return $this->render('@AdminTemplates/pages/seat-number-edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```